# Ошибка 0xc000007b при установке MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, orm

В связи с чем она вылетает в данном случае и как можно её устранить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непонятно как, но проблема была решена удивительным образом - установлена меньшая версия + x32 версия (у меня х64, кто объяснит почему?)

```
А вообще я проделал много разных вещей, которые, возможно, Вам помогут:
```

- scannow в консоли
- Запуск программы от прав администратора + выбор разных версий совместимости;
- Установка .netframwork последней версии;
- Установка Visual C++ Redistributable (Панель управления\Все элементы панели управления\Программы и компоненты --> должны быть 2005/2008/2010/2012/2013/2015 в двух экземплярах: 32 + 64, кроме 2005, там почему-то один;
- На всякий случай попробуйте CCleaner'ом почистить всё и проверить на ошибки.
- Также может не хватать библиотек, посмотрите
  видео, там есть толковые слова.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHUYkD_VT5A&t=24s